# Js line disappearing in browser console window

Tags: javascript, html, console

When I hit enter after writing some lines of Js on console window of a browser it's getting disappeared.

And I'm not getting any output printed on console window.
Like output of consol.log();
Or anything.
Someone help me with this problem.

Comment: If your browser is Chrome, [look here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/log/#level). It looks like a log levels setting issue.

Comment: You may have accidentally entered something into the filter field. Clear that.